# ionic range, disable on android

Tags: slider, range, ionic-framework

I am using in my application ionic range slider. But I need it just for showing progress, that meens that I have to disable changing its value by user (it must be readonly).

html looks like this:

```
<input type="range" name="time" min="0" max="60" value="0" ng-model="rangeValue" readonly disabled="disabled"  >
```

on emulator in browser that works as a charm, but on android device I am able to change the value :(.

Any suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you...

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" step="1" readonly disabled>
```

You can put whatever value in value=""